# yeoman mean unknown provider GlobalProvider

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator

It has been a job and a half getting the yeoman [MEAN](https://github.com/jrcryer/generator-mean) generator to work correctly on a windows 8 box - and I don't quite understand why it has such an old version of angular maybe I used the wrong generator I'm brand new to node, bower, grunt etc. anyway I've finally got it working but there is this bit of angular code I've not seen before and I don't really understand what it does but it seems to be causing my error in the index.js it injects 'Global'

```
angular.module('mean.system').controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'Global', function ($scope, Global) {
$scope.global = Global;
```

}]);

but when I run I get an error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: GlobalProvider <- Global
```

I don't see any services called 'Global' in the project - any idea what this is?

Im thinking I just came across an outdated generator but am not sure like I said yeoman etc are completely new to me. Any input on whether or not I should be using a different generator?

Comment: You're injecting it. If you don't know what it is...

Comment: I understand its being injected I just don't know 'what' its trying to inject I assume its a service but there is not a service called 'Global' in the generator-mean project

Comment: I've decided to bail on this 'generator' as I think its old perhaps no longer supported and switched to angular-fullstack - worked right out of the box